# Atom-editor auto-generate .tags/.tags1

Tags: javascript, editor, atom-editor

I'm using Atom as my code editor. Every time I save my code, it autogenerates `.tags` and `tags1` files like the image below.

How can I make Atom stop autogenerating those files??

[image]

Comment: This is likely caused by a third-party package. You can confirm this by running `atom --safe` (launches Atom without third-party packages) and see if the problem persists. You then have to identify the package, see if it has options to disable that feature or disable the package altogether.

Comment: Thanks!! It didn't happen when I opened up atom with `atom --safe`. I'll try to the third party package that is causing this issue!!